# How can I change the color scheme/theme of groff-mom?

Tags: colors, pdf, groff

I know how to change individual macro's colors, but is there a way to globally change all the colors to a different color scheme/theme?

I am using groff-mom.

Example:
It currently looks like this
[image: Document with normal light colors]

I would like to change the colors globally like this
[image: Document with darker colors]

*Note that these documents are just for example, and they were not actually created using groff.*

Comment: The [tag:groff] tag covers everything `groff`. What output format are you looking at? PDF?

Comment: I am outputting to a pdf.